# Is this PHP for loop supposed to run slow?

Tags: php, performance, loops, for-loop

I wrote the following loop since I have to repeat the same/similar code 25 times. I may need to repeat more, but for now it's at 25.

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 24; $i++) {
  echo "<div class=\"";
  if ($i = 0) {
    echo "overlay";
  } else {
    echo "layer"+$i;
  }
  echo "\">code</div>\n";
}
?>
```

When uploaded to my website, it takes forever to load and then pulls resources from my computer and eventually makes the computer slow.

Comment: Did you want to write `"layer".$i` ?

Comment: @navnav - I'll simplify this for you. Go here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x5jQq/ and open your dev tools...

Comment: It should parse if it wasn't an infinite loop. It was loading my other content very slowly. Now it works thanks to the answers below. It was foolish of me to have missed such a simple mistake. ):

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try changing:

```
if ($i = 0) {
```

to:

```
if ($i == 0) {
```

You're setting $i to 0 on each iteration, not comparing it.

Comment: Hint hint to OP: PHP is not like VB.NET

Comment: Switching between languages is fun; I can't count the number of times that my perfectly valid perl failed to work, simply because I should have been writing in PHP.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't even notice the boolean part... Everything is working well now.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want if ($i == 0)

I suspect you're resetting $i to 0 every time you go through that if loop.

Answer (score 1):

Even better simplification:

```
echo '<div class="overlay">code</div>';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
   echo <<<EOL
<div class="layer$i">code</div>

EOL;
}
```

Assuming that `code` doesn't change within the loop. Also note that your

```
echo "layer"+$i;
```

is incorrect. String concatenation in PHP is done with `.`. You're adding a mathematical addition, so PHP will conver `"layer"` to `0` and you'll end up effectively ouputting only the value of `$i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 24; $i++) {
  echo "<div class=\"";
  if ($i = 0) {
    echo "overlay";
  } else {
    echo "layer"+$i;
  }
  echo "\">code</div>\n";
}
?>
```

Instead of using comparison operation (==), you used assignment operator(=).

Use,

```
if($i == 0){
   echo "// your code  ";
   }
```